# Galleria resize stop working at load()

Tags: jquery, resize, galleria

I have a problem with the resizing in fullscreen that stops working after I load a second gallery. It works perfectly before the load() call. I have tried to get more information about the rescale() function but havent found a way to get it to work.

```
// backstage
  var firstGallery = [
    {
      image:  "img/bg1.jpg"
    },
    {
      image:  "img/bg2.jpg"
    },
    {
      image:  "img/bg3.jpg"
    }
  ];


  // work commercial
  var secondGallery = [
    {
      image:  "img/commers1.jpg"
    },
    {
      image:  "img/commers2.jpg"
    },
    {
      image:  "img/commers3.jpg"
    }
  ];

  // Load fullscreen theme
  Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/fullscreen/galleria.fullscreen.min.js');

  // Intialize Galleria
  $('#gallery').galleria(
    {
      dataSource: firstGallery,
      imageCrop: true,
      autoplay: true,
      transition: "slide",
      thumbnails: false,
      showInfo: true,
      clicknext: true,
      preload: 4,
      swipe: true,

      // maxScaleRatio: 1
    }
  );


  $('#workEditorial').click(function() {
    // byter ut bilderna i #gallery diven
    Galleria.get(0).load(secondGallery);
    Galleria.get(0).setOptions( 'imageCrop', 'false' );

  });

  $('#backstage').click(function() {
    Galleria.get(0).load(firstGallery);
    Galleria.get(0).setOptions( 'imageCrop', 'true' );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call the `.rescale()` after `setOptions`:

```
Galleria.get(0).setOptions( 'imageCrop', 'false' ).rescale();
```

Comment: Thank you David for the answer. I did try that before without result.

Comment: Any other suggestions? Seems like the theme is lost at load() and that can't be right...